# combining ## and _type in preprocessor directives

Tags: c, gcc

What is the purpose of the usage `thread##_type` in this code snippet?
I understand that underscore `t (_t)` is used as a convention for naming to identify types, as is underscore type `(_type)`, often in `typedef` statements. I also understand `##` in `macros` indicate concatenation. Does `_type` has any purpose other than this? (like the usage of double underscore `__FILE__`)?

```
#define THREAD_TYPE(thread)                         
typedef struct                                      \
{                                                   \
   pthread_t pthread;                               \
   int err;                                         \
} thread##_type;
```

Comment: The purpose is to create a new token. It has nothing to do with `__FILE__`

Comment: @StoryTeller I think Xter means to ask if `_type` is a special macro (

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - No offence, but how did you infer that? Xter said they understand `_type` and `_t` are common postfixes.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant to ask whether its a special macro.

Comment: This is creating a typedef with a name derived from the parameter. `THREAD_TYPE( foo )` will create a `typedef foo_type`, so your code can create a `foo_type x` with `x.pthread` and `x.err`. No, `_type` does not expand to anything special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_type` has no special meaning in C. This code is simply decorating the name in a way the author chose, nothing more.